# How can I add an empty value in a selection tag?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have made a form that lets the user to select a year and place they want. The select tag for year is as below:

```
<strong>Tahun: </strong>
<?php
echo ('<select name="tahun">');
for($i = date("Y"); $i < date("Y")+11; $i++)
{
    echo ('<option value=  "'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>');          
}   
echo ('</select>');
?>
```

And code for place selection tag as below:

```
<strong>Tempat: </strong>
<?php
echo ('<select name="tempat">');
$query = "SELECT *FROM bilik WHERE kosong = 'tak'";
$results = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error._LINE_);
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){      
    echo ('<option value= "'.$row['nama'].'">'.$row['nama'].'</option>');
}
echo ('</select>');
?>
```

Now, what I want to do is add empty value with a message "Please choose one" for both selection tag. So, can someone help me how to add that value and message in this tag?

Comment: Also, what's wrong with `echo(<option value="Please choose one"</option>); while(...)`?

Comment: sorry my bad .. @KenWhite  anyways thanks for edit it

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: okay i've got it thanks for helping @KenWhite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to add `select` options to your code, this is how it should be:

```
<?php
echo ('<select name="tempat">');
$query = "SELECT *FROM bilik WHERE kosong = 'tak'";
$results = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error . _LINE_);
echo ('<option>Please choose one </option>'); // Added this here
while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo ('<option value= "' . $row['nama'] . '">' . $row['nama'] . '</option>');
}
echo ('</select>');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add default option with empty value then you should add as `<option value="">Select...</option>`

```
<strong>Tahun: </strong>
<?php
   echo '<select name="tahun">';
   echo '<option value="">Please Choose One</option>';
   for($i = date("Y"); $i < date("Y")+11; $i++)
    {
     echo '<option value=  "'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';          
    }   
   echo '</select>';
?>
```

and

```
<?php

      $query = "SELECT *FROM bilik WHERE kosong = 'tak'";
      $results = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error . _LINE_);

      echo '<select name="tempat">';
      echo '<option value="">Please choose one</option>'; //Please choose one 
      while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<option value= "' . $row['nama'] . '">' . $row['nama'] . '</option>';
      }
     echo '</select>';
?>
```